# Is there a workaround for font dimming during CSS3 opacity transitions?

Tags: firefox, css, transition, css-transitions

I've got an HTML element where the opacity changes on hover (using a CSS3 transition). The problem is that in Firefox (on Windows at least), the text (a <p>) within the element (a <div>) dims perceptibly during the opacity change, then "pops back" to the way it should be a fraction of a second after the transition ends. Like this (video):

http://screencast.com/t/zzWc9EF8wq4c

This problem does not occur in Chrome.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Any workarounds?

Comment: Off the top of my head try setting position: relative on the text?

Comment: That didn't help, I'm afraid :( I guess I could separate the child p from the parent div and position it absolutely on top of the div, but that would make things more complicated. (I also need to show and hide the whole thing...)

Comment: @martinpolley - are you applying a background to the p element? Or to the div? This problem usually happens when element does not have a background color set (altough usually in IE).

Comment: @easwee No, the background color is on the div. But setting an explicit background color on the p as well does not seem to make any difference :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an RGBA color on your elements and transition that instead of transitioning the elements opacity (because this cascades down to all lower elements in the DOM tree). Thats how i do it on my projects :)

Comment: OK, I tried this, and it works very nicely. Thanks :)

But now I have a new problem—what to do in IE? I've tried setting a fallback background-color with RGB instead of RGBa (by declaring it first), but it's not working for me, which means that in IE, the element has no background color at all :( 

Any ideas?

Comment: In the end, I got around this problem by using conditional comments for IE. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Thats fine, feel feed to upvote and set as accepted answer to help others :)

Comment: Marked as accepted. I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet though :(

Thanks again!